# Enamine Formation in a Diketone

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis, carbonyl-compounds

I am trying to form an enamine, and I was trying to figure out if the following reaction is possible:
[image]

Would this reaction terminate after the formation of the shown product, or will the other carbonyl also react, producing a final product with two enamine groups? If so, is it possible under any conditions to stop the reaction after the formation of the first enamine?

Comment: You won't form a second enamine because the mono-enamine is a vinylogous amide. I suggest placing the diketone (dihydroresorcinol) in an inert solvent (THF?) with anhydrous MgSO4. Add excess condensed dimethylamine.  The reaction may have an exotherm.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: The MgSO4 is to absorb water. Filter and evaporate.